go postgres sometimes increases processing time
I have primitive task in testing - post http request to create row in postgres. Here is the func:
func CreateNemBannerStorage(db *sql.DB, tags []string, feature, active string, content []string) (*BannerId, error) {
query := `
INSERT INTO
    banners_storage(tag_list, features_id, title_banner, text_banner, url_banner, banner_state)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
RETURNING id_banner;
`

stmt, err := db.Prepare(query)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer stmt.Close()
rows, err := stmt.Query(pq.Array(tags), feature, content[0], content[1], content[2], active)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer rows.Close()

var bannerId BannerId
if rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(&bannerId.ID)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
}

return &bannerId, nil

}

And here is the initter:
func (p *Post) CreateNewBanner(db *sql.DB, token, feature, active string, content, tags []string) (int, *postsql.BannerId, error) {
avaliable, adminState, err := getsql.GetAdminState(db, token)
if err != nil {
    return 500, nil, err
}
if avaliable == false {
    return 401, nil, err
}
if adminState == false {
    return 403, nil, err
}

today1 := time.Now()
bannerId, err := postsql.CreateNemBannerStorage(db, tags, feature, active, content)
today2 := time.Now()
duration := today2.Sub(today1)
milliseconds := duration.Milliseconds()
fmt.Println(milliseconds)
if err != nil {
    return 500, nil, err
}

return 201, bannerId, nil

}

So I start post requests from postman
Usual request time: ~3-4ms, but sometimes it grows for one/two operations grows uf to 200ms, usually 55ms. I debbuged postgres func and got that it was it. Need help to make it smooth

My postman request options: 0ms delay (1ms impacts same), 10000 iterations

decreased time to 100ms delay  no difference

Db struct
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS banners_storage(
id_banner  SERIAL,
tag_list INTEGER[],
features_id INTEGER,
title_banner TEXT,
text_banner TEXT,
url_banner TEXT,
banner_state BOOLEAN,
created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (id_banner)
);

«I debbuged postgres func and got that it was it.»–what exactly is "postgres func" in your question?

CreateNewBanner - func to create banner row using func CreateNemBannerStorage. Postgres func - is CreateNemBannerStorage func, where I execute postgres. So I captured metrics of db request time

So you've narrowed the issue down to something to do with the connection between your application and postgresql, postgresql's planner and executor and the hardware it is running on. Excellent. You've then provided zero details about any of that.

Richard has a point. Is that PG instance completely isolated (that is, does only your program ever works with it)? If not, are you able to figure out whether some other program creates spikes of load on that instance? Can you see host performance metrics of that PG instance–such as disk and CPU utilization? Is it possible to temporarily make PG log query exeution timings and then check whether unexpected spikes measured in your program correlate with longer execution times recorded in the produced log? It's impossible to tell what can be a problem by looking at high-level Go code.
